# ng-repeat within modal view not working

Tags: html, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to display a table of results from a mongodb but im just trying to gather some structure and learn at the same time so ive just got some dummy data at the moment within a controller

```
app.controller('modal-controller', function($scope) {
$scope.fakeResults = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "location": "3",
        "value": "27.5"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "location": "3",
        "value": "27.0"
    }, {
        "id": "3",
        "location": "3",
        "value": "27.2"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "location": "3",
        "value": "27.9"
    }, {
        "id": "5",
        "location": "3",
        "value": "28.5"
    } 
];
});
```

The html for the modal section im trying to view the results is below

```
    <div ng-controller="modal-controller" class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h2>Temperature Table</h2>
                        <hr class="star-primary">
                        <p>TEST TEXT {{ fakeResults }}</p>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="result in fakeResults">
                                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                <td>{{result.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{result.location}}</td>
                                <td>{{result.value}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/cabin.png" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                        <p>This page will be used to display simple table of temperature results</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline item-details">
                            <li>Hardware:
                                <strong>Tinkerforge equipment linked</strong>
                            </li>
                            <li>Software:
                                <strong>Github Link</strong>
                            </li>
                            <li>Difficulty:
                                <strong>1</strong>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The results are visible after viewing the whole sample of data but not with ng-repeat. Not overly sure why this is but ive hopefully narrowed it down to something around the ng-repeat.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot table tag around your tbody

```
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="result in fakeResults">
                                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                <td>{{result.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{result.location}}</td>
                                <td>{{result.value}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```